# Alamofire gives error in Swift 3, Xcode 8

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8, alamofire

I was using Alamofire in Xcode 7.3.1, Swift 2 so far. But now I wanted to migrate to Swift 3. I was using pods to update the Alamofire library. Now, I am getting 386 errors in my code from Alamofire. What could be the reason? Isn't Alamofire made for Swift 3 yet? Or is it some mistake I am doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have not updated your cocoa pods

Execute the follwoing on your terminal:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods --pre
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your pods. For alamofire latest version use:

```
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Alamo fire is available for swift 3 , I think you should update your pods even if you get a error it's your code problem,

Go to terminal and run  this command : pod update